# Viewing public calendars in V3?

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've read that in the V3 calendar API, every request must be authorized.  Is there a way to view public calendars in the new API that doesn't require any authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the calendar is made public in the settings and is not owned by a domain that restricts the maximum access level, you can access it without authentication. For example there is a public calendar for movie releases with id 6qk18mdsijg7s1p800gbg7bmh4@group.calendar.google.com
You can successfully retrieve it in the calendar API explorer without clicking on authorize:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.list?calendarId=6qk18mdsijg7s1p800gbg7bmh4%2540group.calendar.google.com&_h=2&

Comment: Do you have a link to the API calls that use this type of access, instead of the API explorer?

Comment: When I use the API directly, I get this error: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup"

Comment: You will still need to register in the developer console and provide an API key, even if you skip the Oauth token. Follow the steps here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth