# How to read a public Google calendar from a mobile app without authenticating?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need to read many Google public calendars from an iOS app.  I don't want to require users to authenticate.

The docs and samples from Google all seem to assume an app is reading a user's private calendar, which naturally would require authentication.

I see something called a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) mentioned, but it's not obvious that it should be used in mobile apps.

I don't need to use one of the SDKs if I can just retrieve JSON from some URL.

This question has been asked on StackOverflow in the past, but I haven't found an answer which still works.  Google changed their API in 2014.

How can I read a public calendar from a mobile app without authenticating?

Comment: You can, use this `GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{YOUR_CALENDARID}/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`. But you'll need to create an API even though you can skip the OAuth for viewing the calendar. For additional information about the implementation about [Accessing the Calendar Without OAuth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714981/viewing-public-calendars-in-v3). I hope this helps.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Thanks.  However, I can't figure out what to put for API_KEY.  I've registered an app in the dev console, but I only see an ID and client secret.

Comment: @royco there is option to create new API_KEY if you don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given in the comments by @Mr.Rebot and @Vipin Sharma.  Just use this URL:

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{YOUR_CALENDARID}/events?key={Y‌​OUR_API_KEY}`

One can get an API_KEY from the Google developer console.  It's an option I overlooked at first.